# Yeoman Error: Cannot find module 'globby'

Tags: yeoman-generator

I am following the steps to use the Yeoman generator meanjs, but I am getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'globby'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

at your root directory
npm install --save globby@3.0.0

restart